Is there a way to get the number of template project members via the Autodesk Construction Cloud API?
I'm writing an ACC project creation automation based on a template workflow that automatically adds all template project members. It utilizes Step 3A in this Autodesk tutorial, where adding a project admin will trigger the assignment of all template project members to the project.
For the context of my problem, it's important to distinguish between the two types of members in an ACC Project Template:

Template Configuration Members: Users who can use or contribute to the template but are not automatically assigned to projects created from the template. These users are managed in the Template Configuration area of the ACC project template UI, under permissions.

Template Project Members: Users automatically added to a project created from a project template. These users are managed in the Project Member page of the ACC project template UI, via the "Members" tab.


While having ACC automatically add project members is a nice feature, I've observed that this process can take anywhere from 2-18 minutes for no more than 4 members. In this Autodesk webinar, the presenter mentions this time lag and suggests using the GET project users request on the project and waiting until there are more than one users in the project to confirm all project members have been added. However, in terms of automating this process, this approach will not work for the edge case where a template has no project members, because project users will never exceed one.
Therefore, to ensure exactly all members have been automatically added, I've attempted to:

Poll the template using a GET projects request with filter[classification] == template.

Check the number of members in that template.

Wait until the project user count reaches that number.


However, I discovered that while the GET projects request returns a memberCount property for the template, it represents the number of template configuration members, not template project members.
My questions are:

Is there a way to get the number of template project members through an API request?

Are there any alternative solutions to confirm when the adding members process has completed, given the constraints described?


Thank you for your assistance!

The answer to your 2 questions as the day of 2024, May 28th:
Question 1: Is there a way to get the number of template project members through an API request?
Answer: No, there is no API to get the template members(or number of template members) from a template.
Question 2: Are there any alternative solutions to confirm when the adding members process has completed, given the constraints described?
Answer: Unfortunately, since the detail of JobId is not exposed, there is not an ideal solution to get the status of the new created project. How about including a dummy template project member with least product access(only Docs) for the checking purpose?
